# count the number of times a value appears in a column where liked_id matches likes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

does anyone know how you would count the total number of times a value appears in a single column.

for instance my table looks like:

```
user_id  |  liked_id   |   likes

   3             1           1   
   4             1           1
```

what i want to do is count the total of the likes column where liked_id matches.

So liked_id 1 has 2 likes?

can someone please show me how i might do this?

```
function count_likes() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT likes, count(*) FROM ptb_likes GROUP BY liked_id";
            $count_likes_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($count_likes_set);
            return $count_likes_set;        
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT liked_id, SUM(likes) FROM ptb_likes GROUP BY liked_id
```

Answer (score 1):

you should grouped them by `liked_id`

```
SELECT liked_id, count(*)  totalLikes
FROM ptb_likes 
GROUP BY liked_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the number of rows with like_id of 1,

```
SELECT liked_id, COUNT(likes) FROM ptb_likes WHERE liked_id = 1;
```

If you want the the frequency of each like_id:

```
SELECT liked_id, COUNT(likes) FROM ptb_likes GROUP BY liked_id;
```

As a note: don't use SUM as that adds all the values of like_id, and if you have a like_id greater than 1, your count will be wrong.  Use count instead.